What section of PhD thesis should my standpoint be in?
My research is at the intersection of technology and autism (but it's mostly technology focused). I'm approaching things from a particular standpoint of autism (i.e. neuroafirmative, neurocosmopolitan, counterventionalist, which basically comes down to saying the world is diverse and autistic people are part of this diversity, they are human beings and don't need to be fixed but there are ways they can be better supported). I'm expecting my lit review to be mostly about previous autism+technology projects and I'm thinking it probably doesn't make sense for the methodology section but maybe I'm wrong?
Can anyone please advise, what chapter of a PhD thesis should this be covered in? Is there a better or more commonly used term for this type of information than "standpoint".

This depends upon your specific thesis structure and that depends upon your specific university, college, and/or department guidelines as well as the preferences of you advisor/committee members who will sign off on your thesis. To echo @xxxxxxxxx, ask them.

Thank you for your comments. I have previously discussed this with my supervisor. They are the one advising I include a standpoint (to clarify I am familiar with Standpoint Theory but they are not, so this is not the meaning they are applying). They are not sure themselves on where it should be located within the thesis. There are no formal guidelines available locally in my University or Department on where such information might best be placed.This is a PhD focusing on building and designing technology for autistic children.

Do they/you mean a "positionality statement"? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positionality_statement

Do you mean a "theoretical approach"? Then, the background section (between introduction and methods) might be appropriate for giving a core definition of the concepts - it's not just for citing previous research findings. If you mean a "positionality statement" as suggested by Bryan Krause, then it could be part of a methods section, where you discuss the ethical considerations and potential biases of your methodology. Do check with your supervisor, though, as they would be familiar with discipline specific conventions.
